# Find dominating strategies in a game

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

**Problem**
Colonel Blotto can send each of his five companies to one of ten locations whose importance is valued at $1, 2, 3, . . . , 10$, respectively. No more than one company can be sent to any one location. His opponent, Count Baloney, must simultaneously do the same with his four companies. A commander who
attacks an undefended location captures it. If both commanders attack the
same location, the result is a standoff at that location. A commander’s payoff
is the sum of the values of the locations he captures minus the sum of the
values of the locations captured by the enemy. Find all dominating strategies of each player.

**My attempt**
First of all, we need to decide how many strategies each player has. I think it's $10 \choose 5$ and $10 \choose 4$ for the first and second players respectively.
Next idea is that since player $1$ has more companies (5 vs 4), he should use location $5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$ as if player $2$ places his $4$ units to the $4$ locations within $5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$, player $1$ still receives more.

Comment: Let $B_1$ denote the base strategy of Colonel Blotto of **always** covering bases $(6)$ through $(10)$, with the understanding that Count Baloney knows this.  I don't think that there is any strategy or combination of strategies that Count Baloney might conjure which would ever make $B_1$ less effective than any other strategy or combination of strategies that Colonel Blotto might consider.  The point is, that for any of $(1)$ through $(5)$ that Count Baloney *wins*, there exists one of $(6)$ through $(10)$ that Count Baloney *loses* that he **otherwise** would not have lost.

Comment: The *parallel* consideration holds, for Colonel Blotto.  When considering any alteration to strategy $B_1$, for any of $(1)$ through $(5)$ that Colonel Blotto *therefore* achieves a *superior* result (i.e. winning when he would have tied, or tieing when he would have lost), there exists one of $(6)$ through $(10)$ where Colonel Blotto achieves an *inferior result* (i.e. losing when he would have tied, or tieing, when he would have won).